# A* pathfinding for integer Vectors

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, pathfinding, a-star

This class is for calculating the shortest path in a 2D World (without minding obstacles).

I'm using the A* algorithm and 2D Vectors (from the SFML Framework).
It is working but takes (a lot of) time for higher amount of coordinates.

It takes 4 seconds to calculate the path from one edge of the map to the other.

Example from my Logs: (so you can see the coordinate range i meant)

> Searching from : [Vector2i] X(100) Y(100) to: [Vector2i] X(3945) Y(4046)
>
> Time needed: 4003ms

This is a lot for real time interaction and it's not even checking for obstacles.

I'm probably doing it not very efficient, so i hope you have some advice for me.

EDIT: Changed code to use Sets instead of Lists

```
 public static class AStar
    {
        protected class Location: IComparable<Location>
        {
            public Vector2i pos;
            public int f;
            public int g;
            public int h;
            public int weight;
            public Location parent;

            public Location(Vector2i pos)
            {
                this.pos = pos;
                f = 0;
                g = 0;
                h = 0;
                weight = 1;
                parent = null;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                Location other = obj as Location;
                return this.pos.X == other.pos.X && this.pos.Y == other.pos.Y;
            }

            public int CompareTo([AllowNull] Location other)
            {
                if (this.Equals(other))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (other.f < this.f)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }

        public static Path Search(Vector2i start, Vector2i target)
        {
            Location current = null;
            SortedSet<Location> openList = new SortedSet<Location>();
            HashSet<Location> closedList = new HashSet<Location>();
            Location targetLocation = new Location(target);
            openList.Add(new Location(start));
            while (openList.Any())
            {
                current = openList.First();
                closedList.Add(current);
                openList.Remove(current);
                if (current.Equals(targetLocation))
                {
                    return CreateResultPath(current);
                }
                List<Location> possibleNeighbors = GetPossibleNeighbors(current);
                foreach (Location neighbor in possibleNeighbors)
                {
                    // neighbor must not be in closedSet
                    if (closedList.FirstOrDefault(location => location.Equals(neighbor)) == null)
                    {
                        // calculating neighbor
                        neighbor.g = current.g + neighbor.weight;
                        neighbor.h = CalcDistance(neighbor.pos, target);
                        neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                        neighbor.parent = current;

                        Location oldNeighbor = openList.FirstOrDefault(location => location.Equals(neighbor));
                        if (oldNeighbor == null)
                        {
                            openList.Add(neighbor);
                        }
                        // neighbor is already in openList, checking if this path is better
                        else
                        {
                            if (neighbor.g < oldNeighbor.g)
                            {
                                openList.Remove(oldNeighbor);
                                openList.Add(neighbor);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static Path CreateResultPath(Location result)
        {
            List<Vector2i> resultPath = new List<Vector2i>();
            while (result != null)
            {
                resultPath.Add(result.pos);
                result = result.parent;
            }
            resultPath.Reverse();
            return new Path(resultPath.ToArray());
        }

        private static List<Location> GetPossibleNeighbors(Location current)
        {
            Vector2i currentPos = current.pos;
            List<Location> possibleNeighbors = new List<Location>();
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y)));
            return possibleNeighbors;
        }

        private static int CalcDistance(Vector2i current, Vector2i target)
        {
            return Math.Abs(target.X - current.X) + Math.Abs(target.Y - current.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not use `List` for `openList` and `closedList`: for each processed vertex, you iterate over the entire `openList` (twice!) to find the minimum element in linear time, and for each neighbour, you iterate over the entire `closedList`... They should probably be `SortedSet`s instead (`HashSet` might do for `closedList`). The line `neighbor.f = neighbor.g = neighbor.h` seems to have a bug (should use a `+`).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate With Sorted Set it actually takes more time than before even though i can now just say openSet.First() instead of min and then First(minObject).
I think adding an element to the SortedList takes more time than it saves.

Comment: It should be logarithmic (constant-ish for `HashSet`) in time complexity if used correctly though. Could you show your code with `SortedSet`s instead of `List`s? (and have you fixed the `neighbor.f = neighbor.g = neighbor.h` line?) Priority queues can also be used for the same time complexity with `SortedSet`s, but a noticeably lower constant factor.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate i've edited the code in the original post. And yes i did fix the neighbor.f line.

Comment: I think the guess I had was correct: `FirstOrDefault` on sets still iterates over the set in linear time, with a higher constant factor than regular `List`s. I can't recall what methods are used for searching in sets in C#, but that should be easy to find.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate You were right. FirstOrDefault() from System.Linq doesnt perform well on Sets.
Instead i used only methods given by the set itself instead of those extension methods.
The given example which took 6 seconds now only takes 50ms. It saves time over an factor of 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution suggested by @mypronounismonicareinstate.

The time save is a bit more than factor 100. The average calculation time was ~6s now it's ~50-60ms.

First of all using Sets instead of Lists. In terms of iterating and removing items, Sets are way more faster.

Second: Using SortedSet to save the check for the minimum f in OpenList. And use HashSet for closedList.

Im my original solution this took 2 times iterating the whole list.

Third: Not using System.Linq in Combination with Sets if you want to iterate.
System.Linq will always iterate through the whole set.

The final code:

```
public static class AStar
    {
        protected class Location: IComparable<Location>
        {
            public Vector2i pos;
            public int f;
            public int g;
            public int h;
            public int weight;
            public Location parent;

            public Location(Vector2i pos)
            {
                this.pos = pos;
                f = 0;
                g = 0;
                h = 0;
                weight = 1;
                parent = null;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                Location other = obj as Location;
                return this.pos.X == other.pos.X && this.pos.Y == other.pos.Y;
            }

            public int CompareTo([AllowNull] Location other)
            {
                if (this.Equals(other))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (other.f < this.f)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }

        public static Path Search(Vector2i start, Vector2i target)
        {
            Location current = null;
            SortedSet<Location> openList = new SortedSet<Location>();
            HashSet<Location> closedList = new HashSet<Location>();
            Location targetLocation = new Location(target);
            openList.Add(new Location(start));
            while (openList.Any())
            {
                current = openList.First();
                closedList.Add(current);
                openList.Remove(current);
                if (current.Equals(targetLocation))
                {
                    return CreateResultPath(current);
                }
                List<Location> possibleNeighbors = GetPossibleNeighbors(current);
                foreach (Location neighbor in possibleNeighbors)
                {
                    // neighbor must not be in closedSet
                    if (!closedList.Contains(neighbor))                        
                    {
                        // calculating neighbor
                        neighbor.g = current.g + neighbor.weight;
                        neighbor.h = CalcDistance(neighbor.pos, target);
                        neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                        neighbor.parent = current;

                        openList.TryGetValue(neighbor, out Location oldNeighbor);
                        if (oldNeighbor == null)
                        {
                            openList.Add(neighbor);
                        }
                        // neighbor is already in openList, checking if this path is better
                        else
                        {
                            if (neighbor.g < oldNeighbor.g)
                            {
                                openList.Remove(oldNeighbor);
                                openList.Add(neighbor);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static Path CreateResultPath(Location result)
        {
            List<Vector2i> resultPath = new List<Vector2i>();
            while (result != null)
            {
                resultPath.Add(result.pos);
                result = result.parent;
            }
            resultPath.Reverse();
            return new Path(resultPath.ToArray());
        }

        private static List<Location> GetPossibleNeighbors(Location current)
        {
            Vector2i currentPos = current.pos;
            List<Location> possibleNeighbors = new List<Location>();
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X - 1, currentPos.Y)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y + 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y - 1)));
            possibleNeighbors.Add(new Location(new Vector2i(currentPos.X + 1, currentPos.Y)));
            return possibleNeighbors;
        }

        // Chebyshev Distance
        private static int CalcDistance(Vector2i current, Vector2i target)
        {
            return Math.Max(Math.Abs(target.X - current.X), Math.Abs(target.Y - current.Y));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have noticed what seems to be another bug: your GetPossibleNeighbors function seems to generate neighbours on a grid with Chebyshev distance (as in, moving like a chess king; \$\max(\Delta x, \Delta y)\$), but the heuristic uses the rectilinear/taxicab/Manhattan distance (as in, moving to any of the 4 neighbours with a common side; \$\Delta x + \Delta y\$). This makes the heuristic non-admissible (it overestimates diagonal paths) and voids your warranty and you don't necessarily get shortest paths.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate yes you are right. I'm going to adjust the CalcDistance Function then.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate the CalcDistance Function should be correct now.